# Jquery DataTables not working for append html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a `jQuery DataTables` style for the responsive layout, but when I use javascript to append `<td>Mycode</td>` in the table, then the dataTables style not working, any idea?

Comment: Can you share your code here? if you want to add a new Data row in Jquery dataTable you can use datatable's row.add method

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask here. HINT: Post code and effort

Answer (score 1):

DataTable does not work in append in javascript, because after calling `.DataTable` method our append method calls. If you debug your javascript code, then you will find that `.DataTable` call before `.append`. Check our table body, it does not render at time when `.DataTable` calls. So write `.DataTable` method after `.append` method.

```
$('#grdWrkServiceEntry').append(tableBody);
$('#grdWrkServiceEntry').DataTable();
```

I also faced the same problem, but now it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here We go:

In documentation I find it:

```
New rows can be added to a DataTable very easily using the row.add() API method.
```

Try add new row as this like code:

function row.add() can help you;)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var t = $('#yourDataTableId').DataTable();
        var counter = 1;

        $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
            t.row.add( [
                counter +'.1',
                counter +'.2',
                counter +'.3',
                counter +'.4',
                counter +'.5'
            ] ).draw( false );

            counter++;
        } );


        $('#addRow').click();
    } );
<button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
```

Hope it helps;)